# How to get Exact User location by Using maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

May be similar question asked before. But I am in the middle of finding the location. When I try the following code it shows my internet providers location. and which doesnot show my current location.

```
function ipLookUp () {
  $.ajax('http://ip-api.com/json')
  .then(
      function success(response) {
          console.log('User\'s Location Data is ', response);
          console.log('User\'s Country', response.country);
          getAdress(response.lat, response.lon)
},

      function fail(data, status) {
          console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of',
                      status);
      }
  );
}
function getAddress (latitude, longitude) {
  $.ajax('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&key=***************************************')
  .then(
    function success (response) {
      console.log('User\'s Address Data is ', response)
    },
    function fail (status) {
      console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of',
                  status)
    }
   )
}
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  // check if geolocation is supported/enabled on current browser
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   function success(position) {   // for when getting location is a success
     console.log('latitude', position.coords.latitude, 'longitude', position.coords.longitude);
     getAddress(position.coords.latitude,  position.coords.longitude);
   },
function error(error_message) {  // for when getting location results in an error
    console.error('An error has occured while retrieving  location', error_message);
    ipLookUp();
 }
);
} else {
  // geolocation is not supported
  // get your location some other way
  console.log('geolocation is not enabled on this browser')
  ipLookUp()
}
```

It shows my ISP city name. But I want my current location name like this sample image.
[image]
This is sample image. and it shows my current city and street name in google search results page. But when I use the above code.it shows like this.

```
AS55836 Reliance Jio Infocomm Limited"
city: "Coimbatore"
country: "India"
isp: "RJIL Tamilnadu LTE SUBSCRIBER PUBLIC"
org: "Reliance Jio infocomm ltd"
```

Looking some experts advice to trace the location exactly.

Comment: I want to know the reason for voting it down.